# Why does this code using non-qualified "std::swap" function compile?

Tags: c++, std

In a .cpp file I implement a bubble_sort algorithm. Inside the bubble_sort function I use swap(a, b). However I don't specify "using name space std" in this cpp file. (Actually there is no header in this .cpp file) I still could complile the program without any warning or error. I know that if I want to use some customary function in that bubble_sort function, I need to at lease declare that function in the same file. But I don't understand why I don't need to do any thing for the swap. Below is my cpp file:

bubble_sort.cpp

```
template <typename Type>
void bubble_sort(Type* originarray, int lengthofarray)
{
    int ii=lengthofarray-1;
    while(ii>0)
    {
        for (int jj=0;jj<ii;jj++)
        {
            if (originarray[jj]>originarray[jj+1])
                swap(originarray[jj],originarray[jj+1]);
        }
        ii--;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a nonstandard compiler behaviour (or some rude library) introducing it into the global scope. I don't think this use warrants ADL here.

Comment: Your function is a template.  Are you actually instantiating it?

Comment: And if you are instantiating it, might you be instantiating it with a type in the `std` namespace, or a type derived from a type in the `std` namespace?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I use Microsoft Visual 2010 in Code::block

Comment: @arx I have another main.cpp which instantiate the function and also have "using namespace std" in the beginning. I tried to remove this sentense and the program report an error on swap.

Comment: @hvd I don't quite understand what you mean... In the main.cpp I just use int array to test.

Comment: @user3614235 Then my comment doesn't apply to your situation, but in case you're interested anyway, consider `struct S : std::vector<int> { }; S a, b; int main() { swap(a, b); }` (don't forget to include the appropriate headers). This compiles without any `using std::swap;` or `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1):

First, to properly test template code (at least with MSVC), you should *instantiate* it.

Moreover, if you try your code with some class that is in the `std` namespace, `std::swap()` can be picked by the compiler via [**ADL (Koenig) lookup**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).

Comment: The fellow's name is Andrew Koenig, not Keonig. Getting names right can be tricky as you've shown, getting them wrong can be seen as disrespectful, so perhaps it would be better to just call it ADL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the name typo. Of course, I didn't mean to be disrespectful. I've fixed the name.